# Are the projections of a Gaussian random vector onto two independent isotropic random vectors independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $Z\sim N(0,I_{n})$ be a standard normal Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be two isotropic and independent random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. They also have the same distribution, although I'm not sure if this matters. Can we say anything about the projection values $\left<Z, V_1\right>$ and $\left<Z, V_2\right>$?

I know that if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are fixed orthogonal vectors, then the projection values are independent. What if they're not? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Work out $E\exp(it\langle Z, V_1\rangle + iu \langle Z, V_2\rangle)$, if you can, taking expectations over all 3 vectors.

Comment: Great, I'll do that.

Comment: It's easy to do if both $V_i \sim N(0,I_n)$.

Comment: They're not. They're ``sparse symmetric Bernoulli'', which means $\mathbb{P}(V_{1, i}=1)=\mathbb{P}(V_{1, i}=-1)=p/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(V_{1, i}=0)=1-p$.

Comment: Then the two projections are not independent.